# oracle query to get max hour every day, and corresponding row values

Tags: oracle, group-by, max

I'm having a hard time creating a query to do the following:

I have this table, called LOG:

```
ID | INSERT_TIME             | LOG_VALUE
----------------------------------------
 1 | 2013-04-29 18:00:00.000 | 160473
 2 | 2013-04-29 21:00:00.000 | 154281
 3 | 2013-04-30 09:00:00.000 | 186552
 4 | 2013-04-30 14:00:00.000 | 173145
 5 | 2013-04-30 14:30:00.000 | 102235
 6 | 2013-05-01 11:00:00.000 | 201541
 7 | 2013-05-01 23:00:00.000 | 195234
```

What I want to do is build a query that returns, for each day, the last values inserted (using the max value of INSERT_TIME). I'm only interested in the date part of that column, and in the column LOG_VALUE. So, this would be my resultset after running the query:

```
2013-04-29  154281
2013-04-30  102235
2013-05-01  195234
```

I guess that I need to use GROUP BY over the INSERT_TIME column, along with MAX() function, but by doing that, I can't seem to get the LOG_VALUE. Can anyone help me on this, please?

(I'm on Oracle 10g)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT trunc(insert_time),
       log_value
  FROM (
    SELECT insert_time,
           log_value,
           rank() over (partition by trunc(insert_time)
                            order by insert_time desc) rnk
      FROM log)
 WHERE rnk = 1
```

is one option.  This uses the analytic function `rank` to identify the row with the latest `insert_time` on each day.

Comment: Thanks for the fast answer! Testing right now with my _live_ database (50 million rows)...

Comment: update: took forever, but it got the job done. Many thanks, @Justin !!